# Aggregating data on the client for use in a stacked bar chart

Tags: json, d3.js, highcharts, underscore.js

I am working with [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) and the stacked bar chart. The solution I have been tasked with is to have as few trips back to the server to filter a given data set. The data is only refreshed if the `X-Axis` time frame changes. A user will have a set of filters that they can select via  hierarchical checkbox system.

I have been working with [D3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference) and [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) to handle the array of JSON I am  getting back from the server. However, I am having difficulty understanding how to group the data and represent it in a stacked chart. I found a cool aggregation [extension for Underscore](https://github.com/nicolaspanel/underscore.aggregate), but I am not sure how to setup multiple groupings. I think I would have to map each group then group again. Both libraries seem to do what I want.

Here is the data we are working with:

```
[  
   {  
      "CheckInTime":"2015-06-04T09:25:13.297",
      "CheckinDate":"2015-06-04",
      "Week":"23",
      "Day":"4",
      "DayOfWeek":"5",
      "Month":"6",
      "Year":"2015",
      "TwentyFourHour":"9",
      "Hour":"9 AM",
      "Period":"AM",
      "CheckOutTime":"2015-06-04T09:42:46.927",
      "TotalTimeInOffice":"1053",
      "LocationId":"7",
      "LocationName":"Exam5",
      "VisitId":"62270",
      "B360VisitTypeId":"11",
      "VisitTypeName":"Follow Up Visit",
      "PatientTimeInLocation":"741",
      "PatientLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T09:29:14.530",
      "PatientNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T09:41:35.757",
      "UserProfileId":"2",
      "GroupId":"12",
      "GroupName":"Physicians",
      "StaffTimeInLocation":"330",
      "StaffLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T09:36:05.373",
      "StaffNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T09:41:35.823",
      "StaffLocationStartTime":"2015-06-04T09:36:05.373",
      "StaffLocationEndTime":"2015-06-04T09:41:35.757",
      "TotalPatientWaitTime":"241",
      "TotalPatientWaitTimeInRoomForStaff":"411",
      "TotalTimeWithPatient":"330",
      "TotalTimeToCheckout":"71"
   },
   {  
      "CheckInTime":"2015-06-04T09:25:13.297",
      "CheckinDate":"2015-06-04",
      "Week":"23",
      "Day":"4",
      "DayOfWeek":"5",
      "Month":"6",
      "Year":"2015",
      "TwentyFourHour":"9",
      "Hour":"9 AM",
      "Period":"AM",
      "CheckOutTime":"2015-06-04T09:42:46.927",
      "TotalTimeInOffice":"1053",
      "LocationId":"7",
      "LocationName":"Exam5",
      "VisitId":"62270",
      "B360VisitTypeId":"11",
      "VisitTypeName":"Follow Up Visit",
      "PatientTimeInLocation":"741",
      "PatientLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T09:29:14.530",
      "PatientNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T09:41:35.757",
      "UserProfileId":"21",
      "GroupId":"13",
      "GroupName":"Medical Assistants",
      "StaffTimeInLocation":"205",
      "StaffLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T09:29:19.527",
      "StaffNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T09:32:44.970",
      "StaffLocationStartTime":"2015-06-04T09:29:19.527",
      "StaffLocationEndTime":"2015-06-04T09:32:44.970",
      "TotalPatientWaitTime":"241",
      "TotalPatientWaitTimeInRoomForStaff":"411",
      "TotalTimeWithPatient":"205",
      "TotalTimeToCheckout":"71"
   },
   {  
      "CheckInTime":"2015-06-04T10:18:29.130",
      "CheckinDate":"2015-06-04",
      "Week":"23",
      "Day":"4",
      "DayOfWeek":"5",
      "Month":"6",
      "Year":"2015",
      "TwentyFourHour":"10",
      "Hour":"10 AM",
      "Period":"AM",
      "CheckOutTime":"2015-06-04T11:58:18.783",
      "TotalTimeInOffice":"5989",
      "LocationId":"12",
      "LocationName":"Exam1",
      "VisitId":"62430",
      "B360VisitTypeId":"18",
      "VisitTypeName":"NP Pulmonary Consultation",
      "PatientTimeInLocation":"1232",
      "PatientLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T11:36:39.467",
      "PatientNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T11:57:11.930",
      "UserProfileId":"25",
      "GroupId":"13",
      "GroupName":"Medical Assistants",
      "StaffTimeInLocation":"241",
      "StaffLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T11:44:35.443",
      "StaffNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T11:48:36.093",
      "StaffLocationStartTime":"2015-06-04T11:44:35.443",
      "StaffLocationEndTime":"2015-06-04T11:48:36.093",
      "TotalPatientWaitTime":"4690",
      "TotalPatientWaitTimeInRoomForStaff":"476",
      "TotalTimeWithPatient":"717",
      "TotalTimeToCheckout":"67"
   },
   {  
      "CheckInTime":"2015-06-04T10:18:29.130",
      "CheckinDate":"2015-06-04",
      "Week":"23",
      "Day":"4",
      "DayOfWeek":"5",
      "Month":"6",
      "Year":"2015",
      "TwentyFourHour":"10",
      "Hour":"10 AM",
      "Period":"AM",
      "CheckOutTime":"2015-06-04T11:58:18.783",
      "TotalTimeInOffice":"5989",
      "LocationId":"12",
      "LocationName":"Exam1",
      "VisitId":"62430",
      "B360VisitTypeId":"18",
      "VisitTypeName":"NP Pulmonary Consultation",
      "PatientTimeInLocation":"1232",
      "PatientLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T11:36:39.467",
      "PatientNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T11:57:11.930",
      "UserProfileId":"25",
      "GroupId":"13",
      "GroupName":"Medical Assistants",
      "StaffTimeInLocation":"576",
      "StaffLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T11:34:34.210",
      "StaffNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T11:44:10.407",
      "StaffLocationStartTime":"2015-06-04T11:36:39.467",
      "StaffLocationEndTime":"2015-06-04T11:44:10.407",
      "TotalPatientWaitTime":"4690",
      "TotalPatientWaitTimeInRoomForStaff":"476",
      "TotalTimeWithPatient":"717",
      "TotalTimeToCheckout":"67"
   },
   {  
      "CheckInTime":"2015-06-04T10:25:51.773",
      "CheckinDate":"2015-06-04",
      "Week":"23",
      "Day":"4",
      "DayOfWeek":"5",
      "Month":"6",
      "Year":"2015",
      "TwentyFourHour":"10",
      "Hour":"10 AM",
      "Period":"AM",
      "CheckOutTime":"2015-06-04T10:45:13.737",
      "TotalTimeInOffice":"1162",
      "LocationId":"8",
      "LocationName":"Exam4",
      "VisitId":"63077",
      "B360VisitTypeId":"11",
      "VisitTypeName":"Follow Up Visit",
      "PatientTimeInLocation":"777",
      "PatientLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T10:31:31.477",
      "PatientNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T10:44:28.033",
      "UserProfileId":"8",
      "GroupId":"7",
      "GroupName":"Physician Assistants",
      "StaffTimeInLocation":"611",
      "StaffLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T10:36:22.217",
      "StaffNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T10:46:33.357",
      "StaffLocationStartTime":"2015-06-04T10:36:22.217",
      "StaffLocationEndTime":"2015-06-04T10:44:28.033",
      "TotalPatientWaitTime":"340",
      "TotalPatientWaitTimeInRoomForStaff":"291",
      "TotalTimeWithPatient":"486",
      "TotalTimeToCheckout":"45"
   },
   {  
      "CheckInTime":"2015-06-04T10:25:51.773",
      "CheckinDate":"2015-06-04",
      "Week":"23",
      "Day":"4",
      "DayOfWeek":"5",
      "Month":"6",
      "Year":"2015",
      "TwentyFourHour":"10",
      "Hour":"10 AM",
      "Period":"AM",
      "CheckOutTime":"2015-06-04T10:45:13.737",
      "TotalTimeInOffice":"1162",
      "LocationId":"8",
      "LocationName":"Exam4",
      "VisitId":"63077",
      "B360VisitTypeId":"11",
      "VisitTypeName":"Follow Up Visit",
      "PatientTimeInLocation":"777",
      "PatientLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T10:31:31.477",
      "PatientNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T10:44:28.033",
      "UserProfileId":"21",
      "GroupId":"13",
      "GroupName":"Medical Assistants",
      "StaffTimeInLocation":"195",
      "StaffLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T10:31:36.507",
      "StaffNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T10:34:51.777",
      "StaffLocationStartTime":"2015-06-04T10:31:36.507",
      "StaffLocationEndTime":"2015-06-04T10:34:51.777",
      "TotalPatientWaitTime":"340",
      "TotalPatientWaitTimeInRoomForStaff":"291",
      "TotalTimeWithPatient":"195",
      "TotalTimeToCheckout":"45"
   }

...

 {  
      "CheckInTime":"2015-06-04T17:07:51.747",
      "CheckinDate":"2015-06-04",
      "Week":"23",
      "Day":"4",
      "DayOfWeek":"5",
      "Month":"6",
      "Year":"2015",
      "TwentyFourHour":"17",
      "Hour":"5 PM",
      "Period":"PM",
      "CheckOutTime":"2015-06-04T17:47:48.720",
      "TotalTimeInOffice":"2397",
      "LocationId":"13",
      "LocationName":"Exam2",
      "VisitId":"62816",
      "B360VisitTypeId":"11",
      "VisitTypeName":"Follow Up Visit",
      "PatientTimeInLocation":"1453",
      "PatientLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T17:16:55.890",
      "PatientNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T17:41:08.270",
      "UserProfileId":"8",
      "GroupId":"7",
      "GroupName":"Physician Assistants",
      "StaffTimeInLocation":"731",
      "StaffLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T17:25:21.887",
      "StaffNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T17:37:32.993",
      "StaffLocationStartTime":"2015-06-04T17:25:21.887",
      "StaffLocationEndTime":"2015-06-04T17:37:32.993",
      "TotalPatientWaitTime":"544",
      "TotalPatientWaitTimeInRoomForStaff":"506",
      "TotalTimeWithPatient":"731",
      "TotalTimeToCheckout":"185"
   },
   {  
      "CheckInTime":"2015-06-04T17:07:51.747",
      "CheckinDate":"2015-06-04",
      "Week":"23",
      "Day":"4",
      "DayOfWeek":"5",
      "Month":"6",
      "Year":"2015",
      "TwentyFourHour":"17",
      "Hour":"5 PM",
      "Period":"PM",
      "CheckOutTime":"2015-06-04T17:47:48.720",
      "TotalTimeInOffice":"2397",
      "LocationId":"13",
      "LocationName":"Exam2",
      "VisitId":"62816",
      "B360VisitTypeId":"11",
      "VisitTypeName":"Follow Up Visit",
      "PatientTimeInLocation":"1453",
      "PatientLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T17:16:55.890",
      "PatientNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T17:41:08.270",
      "UserProfileId":"25",
      "GroupId":"13",
      "GroupName":"Medical Assistants",
      "StaffTimeInLocation":"281",
      "StaffLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T17:17:15.890",
      "StaffNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T17:21:56.390",
      "StaffLocationStartTime":"2015-06-04T17:17:15.890",
      "StaffLocationEndTime":"2015-06-04T17:21:56.390",
      "TotalPatientWaitTime":"544",
      "TotalPatientWaitTimeInRoomForStaff":"506",
      "TotalTimeWithPatient":"1648",
      "TotalTimeToCheckout":"185"
   },
   {  
      "CheckInTime":"2015-06-04T17:07:51.747",
      "CheckinDate":"2015-06-04",
      "Week":"23",
      "Day":"4",
      "DayOfWeek":"5",
      "Month":"6",
      "Year":"2015",
      "TwentyFourHour":"17",
      "Hour":"5 PM",
      "Period":"PM",
      "CheckOutTime":"2015-06-04T17:47:48.720",
      "TotalTimeInOffice":"2397",
      "LocationId":"19",
      "LocationName":"Testing",
      "VisitId":"62816",
      "B360VisitTypeId":"11",
      "VisitTypeName":"Follow Up Visit",
      "PatientTimeInLocation":"200",
      "PatientLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T17:41:23.277",
      "PatientNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T17:44:43.603",
      "UserProfileId":"25",
      "GroupId":"13",
      "GroupName":"Medical Assistants",
      "StaffTimeInLocation":"195",
      "StaffLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T17:41:28.257",
      "StaffNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T17:44:43.570",
      "StaffLocationStartTime":"2015-06-04T17:41:28.257",
      "StaffLocationEndTime":"2015-06-04T17:44:43.570",
      "TotalPatientWaitTime":"544",
      "TotalPatientWaitTimeInRoomForStaff":"506",
      "TotalTimeWithPatient":"1648",
      "TotalTimeToCheckout":"185"
   },
   {  
      "CheckInTime":"2015-06-04T17:14:18.983",
      "CheckinDate":"2015-06-04",
      "Week":"23",
      "Day":"4",
      "DayOfWeek":"5",
      "Month":"6",
      "Year":"2015",
      "TwentyFourHour":"17",
      "Hour":"5 PM",
      "Period":"PM",
      "CheckOutTime":"2015-06-04T18:12:50.673",
      "TotalTimeInOffice":"3512",
      "LocationId":"8",
      "LocationName":"Exam4",
      "VisitId":"62872",
      "B360VisitTypeId":"11",
      "VisitTypeName":"Follow Up Visit",
      "PatientTimeInLocation":"2730",
      "PatientLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T17:27:01.943",
      "PatientNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T18:12:31.370",
      "UserProfileId":"8",
      "GroupId":"7",
      "GroupName":"Physician Assistants",
      "StaffTimeInLocation":"441",
      "StaffLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T18:04:55.633",
      "StaffNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T18:12:16.430",
      "StaffLocationStartTime":"2015-06-04T18:04:55.633",
      "StaffLocationEndTime":"2015-06-04T18:12:16.430",
      "TotalPatientWaitTime":"763",
      "TotalPatientWaitTimeInRoomForStaff":"2274",
      "TotalTimeWithPatient":"441",
      "TotalTimeToCheckout":"19"
   },
   {  
      "CheckInTime":"2015-06-04T17:14:18.983",
      "CheckinDate":"2015-06-04",
      "Week":"23",
      "Day":"4",
      "DayOfWeek":"5",
      "Month":"6",
      "Year":"2015",
      "TwentyFourHour":"17",
      "Hour":"5 PM",
      "Period":"PM",
      "CheckOutTime":"2015-06-04T18:12:50.673",
      "TotalTimeInOffice":"3512",
      "LocationId":"8",
      "LocationName":"Exam4",
      "VisitId":"62872",
      "B360VisitTypeId":"11",
      "VisitTypeName":"Follow Up Visit",
      "PatientTimeInLocation":"2730",
      "PatientLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T17:27:01.943",
      "PatientNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T18:12:31.370",
      "UserProfileId":"25",
      "GroupId":"13",
      "GroupName":"Medical Assistants",
      "StaffTimeInLocation":"351",
      "StaffLocationHistoryTimeStamp":"2015-06-04T17:24:16.613",
      "StaffNextLocationTime":"2015-06-04T17:30:07.170",
      "StaffLocationStartTime":"2015-06-04T17:27:01.943",
      "StaffLocationEndTime":"2015-06-04T17:30:07.170",
      "TotalPatientWaitTime":"763",
      "TotalPatientWaitTimeInRoomForStaff":"2274",
      "TotalTimeWithPatient":"186",
      "TotalTimeToCheckout":"19"
   }
]
```

Ultimately, this is what the graph would look like (This is just a mock and the numbers are not representative of my final data):
[image]

I understand, using D3, how to group the data, but I am not sure if I need to run D3 4 times for each section on a bar or if there is a slick way to project the final series I can pass into HighCharts. Each section on the graph is an average for that given set. I also need to count the number of unique visits for each time period. The problem I was facing is that multiple groups may span a Visit so. I suppose I could group by Visit first, count the visits, and then project that data?

For the `Y-Axis` I am thinking I can get the min / max using D3's built in functionality to pull out those values.

Using SQL this is how the data would look (the average columns are in seconds):
[image]

I started a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddivita/pqwpp5gx/) for aggregating the data to get an understating of how grouping works.

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, yes I have, but it doe not answer all my questions nor does it help with how I need to group data. The data in that example is already grouped per state. My data can be grouped by a number of columns.